# gulp-protractor reports skipped tests as failed

Tags: gulp, protractor, jasmine2.0

Running the out of the box 'protractor' command runs my entire E2E directory as expected. Tests that I have disabled are reported as skipped.

However, I'm using gulp-protractor to handle E2E now. But when I run gulp protractor, the disabled tests are reported as failed.

I can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

This is the code that is controlling my gulp e2e tasks.

```
'use strict';

var
  gulp = require('gulp'),
  load = require('gulp-load-plugins')(),
  browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
  paths = gulp.paths;


//starts protractor
function runProtractor(done) {

  gulp.src(paths.e2e + '/**/**/*.js')

    .pipe(load.protractor.protractor(
      {
        configFile: 'protractor.conf.js'
      }
    ))
    .on('error', function (e) {
      // Make sure failed tests cause gulp to exit non-zero
      throw e;
    })
    .on('end', function () {
      // Close browser sync server
      browserSync.exit();
      done();
    });
}

//starts local, selenium, and then starts protractor
gulp.task('protractor:src', ['serve:e2e', 'webdriver-update'], runProtractor);

// Downloads the selenium webdriver
gulp.task('webdriver-update', load.protractor.webdriver_update);
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my gulp task dependencies weren't being processed sequentially, which is what was needed.

This was helpful: http://schickling.me/synchronous-tasks-gulp/